# FROM_TZ in where clause is not returning correct results

Tags: oracle

Why the below sql does not return 2 rows?

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT TO_DATE('17/01/2023 11:42', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') dst_time FROM dual 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT TO_DATE('17/01/2023 17:35', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') dst_time FROM dual
)
SELECT FROM_TZ(CAST(TO_DATE('17/01/2023 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AS TIMESTAMP), 'US/EASTERN') AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' begin_time,  
       FROM_TZ(CAST(to_date('17/01/2023 17:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AS TIMESTAMP), 'US/EASTERN') AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' end_time,
      dst_time
FROM dates
WHERE dst_time BETWEEN FROM_TZ(CAST(to_date('17/01/2023 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AS TIMESTAMP), 'US/EASTERN') AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' 
                    AND FROM_TZ(CAST(to_date('17/01/2023 17:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AS TIMESTAMP), 'US/EASTERN') AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'  
ORDER BY dst_time DESC;
```

Note that `FROM_TZ(CAST(to_date('17/01/2023 17:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AS TIMESTAMP), 'US/EASTERN') AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'` returns 10PM, but the result is not returning "*17/01/2023 17:35*" row. Very strange.

Can some one help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: The output you're getting is legit. Why would you expect a different output? You're selecting the same `FROM_TZ(...), FROM_TZ(...)` where a condition is correctly evaluated. If you want the two records to be different, you shall not hardcode values inside `FROM_TZ` functions.

Comment: Thanks Lemon. I am selecting all rows where date between GMT time of 05:00 AM and 10:00 PM. Since both the rows times are 11:42AM and 05:35PM, it sql should return both of them.

Comment: Your output is [not reproducible](https://dbfiddle.uk/jrkIyD1y). I'm voting to close this post for this reason.

Comment: db fiddle is not returning time component. so you are seeing date part is same. You need to use Sqldeveloper or Toad to see time component.

Comment: Actually, you don't need `... AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'`. Comparison and arithmetic of `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` values are internally always done in UTC time.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is the `dst_time` are `DATE` values:

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT TO_DATE('17/01/2023 11:42', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') dst_time FROM dual 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT TO_DATE('17/01/2023 17:35', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') dst_time FROM dual
) ...
```

Then you compare these `DATE` values with a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` values, i.e. the `DATE` dst_time value is implicitly converted to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` by using

```
FROM_TZ(CAST(dst_time AS TIMESTAMP), SESSIONTIMEZONE)
```

So, the result of your query depends on your current sessions `SESSIONTIMEZONE` which is most likely not `US/EASTERN`

```
SELECT FROM_TZ(CAST(TO_DATE('17/01/2023 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AS TIMESTAMP), 'US/EASTERN') AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' begin_time,  
       FROM_TZ(CAST(to_date('17/01/2023 17:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AS TIMESTAMP), 'US/EASTERN') AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' end_time,
      dst_time
FROM dates
WHERE FROM_TZ(CAST(dst_time AS TIMESTAMP), SESSIONTIMEZONE)
     BETWEEN FROM_TZ(CAST(to_date('17/01/2023 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AS TIMESTAMP), 'US/EASTERN') 
         AND FROM_TZ(CAST(to_date('17/01/2023 17:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AS TIMESTAMP), 'US/EASTERN')
ORDER BY dst_time DESC;
```

As stated in my comment `AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'` in not needed, comparison is done in UTC anyway.

Comment: The problem is that the OP's session time zone probably is `US/EASTERN` but they are explicitly converting all their times to `GMT` and then the default conversion from `DATE` to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` is converting their date to `US/EASTERN` and then it is being compared to the explicitly converted `GMT` values and due to the 5 hour time difference it is not matching.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `WHERE dst_time BETWEEN gmt_timestamp1 AND gmt_timestamp2` is comparing a `DATE` to a range between two `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data types and this is causing an implicit conversion of `dst_time` from `DATE` to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` and ,because it is an implicit conversion, the `WHERE` clause is effectively:

```sql
WHERE FROM_TZ(CAST(dst_time AS TIMESTAMP), SESSIONTIMEZONE)
      BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2023-01-17 00:00:00 US/EASTERN' AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'
      AND     TIMESTAMP '2023-01-17 17:00:00 US/EASTERN' AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'
```

and if the session time zone is not `GMT` then you will have issues comparing the different time zones.

To fix it you need to explicitly convert the left- and right-hand sides of the `BETWEEN` comparison to the same data type and correct time zone (or ensure the implicit conversion uses the correct time zone).

---

Either explicitly cast your timestamps to dates in the `WHERE` filter:

```sql
WITH dates (dst_time) AS (
    SELECT DATE '2023-01-17' + INTERVAL '11:42' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
    SELECT DATE '2023-01-17' + INTERVAL '17:35' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL
)
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2023-01-17 00:00:00 US/EASTERN' AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' begin_time,  
       TIMESTAMP '2023-01-17 17:00:00 US/EASTERN' AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' end_time,
       dst_time
FROM   dates
WHERE  dst_time BETWEEN CAST(TIMESTAMP '2023-01-17 00:00:00 US/EASTERN' AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' AS DATE)
                    AND CAST(TIMESTAMP '2023-01-17 17:00:00 US/EASTERN' AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' AS DATE)
ORDER BY dst_time DESC;
```

Or cast your dates to timestamps in the GMT time zone:

```sql
WITH dates (dst_time) AS (
    SELECT DATE '2023-01-17' + INTERVAL '11:42' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
    SELECT DATE '2023-01-17' + INTERVAL '17:35' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL
)
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2023-01-17 00:00:00 US/EASTERN' AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' begin_time,  
       TIMESTAMP '2023-01-17 17:00:00 US/EASTERN' AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' end_time,
       dst_time
FROM   dates
WHERE  FROM_TZ(CAST(dst_time AS TIMESTAMP), 'GMT')
         BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2023-01-17 00:00:00 US/EASTERN' AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'
             AND TIMESTAMP '2023-01-17 17:00:00 US/EASTERN' AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'
ORDER BY dst_time DESC;
```

Or alter the session time zone to be UTC (or GMT) and then run your query:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = 'UTC';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/InBfo5Wx)

Comment: Thanks a lot Wernfried Domscheit and MT0. Actually the data in the table is stored in GMT timestamp. We want to return all rows up to 5:00 PM EST time which is 10:00PM of GMT now. So dst_time which is in GMT time between TRUNC(SYSDATE) AND GMT(TRUNC(SYSDATE)|| '17:00:00'). My problem is converting of GMT(TRUNC(SYSDATE)|| '17:00:00') using FROM_TZ(CAST(to_date('17/01/2023 17:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AS TIMESTAMP), 'US/EASTERN') AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' is not working correctly.

Comment: @NatureLover `FROM_TZ(CAST(to_date('17/01/2023 17:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AS TIMESTAMP), 'US/EASTERN') AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'` does work correctly. As Wernfried Domscheit said, it is the implicit conversion of `DATE` to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` on the left-hand side of the `BETWEEN` expression that causes the issues with implicitly using the session's time zone instead of the UTC time zone. As I state in my answer, change that to explicitly converting both sides of the `BETWEEN` clause to the same data type so that there is no implicit conversion and there are no issues.

Comment: Thanks MT0. I will do. I am trying to avoid on left side since it is the index column. Appreciate your help.